# I'm getting error during updating my current android studio 3.3 to latest

Tags: android, android-studio

[image]I'm getting an error "plugins/android/lib/layoutlib/data/fonts/RobotoCondensed-Bold.ttf" during updating my android studio version 3.3 to latest version.
please check the screenshot of error when occurs during updating my android studio.sorry for the bad result of the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced such issue & resolved this by downloading the latest android studio from their official site https://developer.android.com/studio instead of upgrading the package from AndroidStudio>Help.

Make sure when you install this new studio, you don't import settings from previous studio. 
Don't know the root cause but solved this in this way, hope it helps.

Comment: If I install new android studio by downloading then possible my previous project list will be lost?

Comment: No, If your project location is different then it will not affected to your projects @TousifIrshad